# MongoDB: Encontrar todos los documentos de una colección que contienen un determinado campo

Tags: mongodb, sql, shell

Tengo una colección de MongoDB llamada `datasets` con varios documentos de este tipo (os adjunto una captura de pantalla de Compass):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A través de una aplicación BI que trabaja sobre MongoDB he actualizado los documentos (creo que todos, pero ésa es mi duda) para que figure en ellos ese objeto de nombre `co_gid`.

¿Qué consulta habría de hacer a través del shell -o, si se puede, del propio Compass- para saber qué documentos contienen ese objeto?

He probado con la siguiente pero el shell me devuelve una línea vacía (la verdad es que apenas uso MongoDB a este nivel):

```
db.datasets.find({"label": "co-gid"});
```

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola, el campo `components` por lo que se aprecia es de tipo `Array`. El mismo contiene una lista de documentos (mostrados en tu imagen como `object`). Tu pregunta es sobre devolver los documentos de ese `Array` que posean `label: "co-gid"`. ¿Es lo que deseas lograr? Sino, por favor aclara un poco más. Saludos

Comment: A lo mejor me he equivocado con la nomenclatura, la estructura de las BBDD no relacionales me confunde bastante. Por documento me refería a cada dataset (es decir, cada una de las "cosas" con la estructura que se muestra en la captura de pantalla) de la colección `datasets`; querría que al hacer la consulta me listase si es posible los datasets que contienen ese objeto de nombre `co_gid`.

Comment: Puedes poner una muestra de código que se pueda replicar en mongo? Para hacer algunas pruebas y poner una respuesta estructurada. Si lo que quieres es quitar esa etiqueta,  se puede eliminar la propiedad en todos los documentos que la tengan. Creo que eso es lo que quieres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viendo el comentario que has puesto, te aclaro alguna cosilla.

Lo que has puesto como ejemplo es un solo documento, todo entero. Si te fijas tiene una clave llamada "_id", y esta clave es única en cada documento y todos tienen que tenerla (si no la asignas tu, se asigna sola).

Ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta, para ver los documentos en los que aparece dentro del array que hay en `components` algún objeto que tenga `'label': 'co_gid'` tendrías que hacer la query así:

```
query = {'components.label': 'co_gid'}
```

Luego ya podrías buscarlos e imprimirlos:

```
docs = db.datasets.find(query)
for doc in docs:
    print(doc)
```

Contarlos:

```
print(db.datasets.count_documents(query))
```

O la operación que quieras realizar sobre ellos.

Comment: Sí, en efecto entendía que lo que aparece en la captura era un documento (hay otros 15 como él, diferentes "datasets") de la colección `datasets`, pero al referirse Mauricio a los `object` como documentos me ha despistado un poco.

Comment: Me da un error de sintaxis:

`> query = {'components.label': 'co_gid'}
{ "components.label" : "co_gid" }
> docs = db.datasets.find(query)
> for doc in docs: print(doc)
2019-09-13T11:03:44.930+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ( after for @(shell):1:4`.

Pero igualmente he conseguido que Compass me liste los documentos simplemente con `{'components.label': 'co_gid'}`.